# I want to use some Arabic letters in card view as text in my android app

Tags: android, arabic, cardview

I want  to use some Arabic letters in card view as text in my android app, how to achieve this. Anyone please help me.

Comment: put arabic letter in string and set that to `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy paste an Arabic string in your string.xml file. The access that string variable through resources. For example put this in your string.xml

```
<string name="message">هذا المجلد يات المحذوفة غير قابلة للإسترجاع.</string>
```

And put this in your code, now mystring variable should be Arabic.

```
String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.message);
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242279/how-to-edit-arabic-string-properly) more suggestions